# Using bash to add file names

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I hope this question is not too abstract for I am slightly new to bash programming. I have a group of files whose name includes two numbers (i.e `gas13_14.5.png`) and I am wondering if there is a way in the shell to rename the file into a combination of the two (`gas27.5.png`) using bash. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please give a more detailed example

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
ls gas13_14.5.png |\
  gawk 'match($0, /^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)(\..*)$/,a){print $0,a[1]""a[2]+a[3]""a[4]}'| xargs -n2 mv
```

The ls output is piped to awk, then we use $0 to print the string without modifications, in other words, the original name of the file.

The next step is use regex capture groups to change file name (`a[1]""a[2]+a[3]""a[4]`).

The result is a combined output that consist of a sequence of *old_file_name* and *new_file_name*.

Finally we pipe the resulting feed through xargs to get the effective rename of the files.

Answer (score 2):

If your filename format doesn't change, you may try the following:

```sh
i=gas13_14.5.png
j=(${i//[^0-9]/ }) # a bash array [13, 14, 5]
mv "$i" "${i/${j[0]}_${j[1]}/$((j[0]+j[1]))}" # Thanks for the comments
#echo "${i/${j[0]}_${j[1]}/`expr ${j[0]} + ${j[1]}`}" ## My original try
```

Let `$i` be the filename, then set `$j` to be an array containing all numbers in `$i` (this is done by replacing non-digits to blanks first, and transform it to an array).

The last step is to replace the number part `${j[0]}_${j[1]}` to the desired number `expr ${j[0]} + ${j[1]}`.

If you have multiple files, wrap it in a loop:

```sh
for i in *.png
do
  j=(${i//[^0-9]/ })
  mv "$i" "${i/${j[0]}_${j[1]}/$((j[0]+j[1]))}"
done
```

Comment: OP wanted file renamed, so you would need to change `echo ` to `mv $i`.

Comment: You could shorten `\`expr ${j[0]} + ${j[1]}\`` to `$((j[0]+j[1]))` so you don't have to resort to an external tool.

Comment: Thank you both. Edited.

Comment: `bash -c 'if [[ "$1" =~ ^gas([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]]+).* ]]; then n="gas$((BASH_REMATCH[1]+BASH_REMATCH[2])).$((BASH_REMATCH[3])).png"; [ ! -e "$n" ] && mv "$1" "$n"; fi ' _ gas*.png`

Comment: prefer `[:digit:]` class name over `[0-9]` range that will fail with some locale settings.

Comment: This almost works, but there is an error pertaining to the files with decimal places. I get a ```bad math expression: operator expected at 13 14.5``` error.

Comment: @Jeramkaram would you please show what's on screen for `echo ${j[@]}` and `echo ${i//[^0-9]/ }` and `echo ${i//[^[:digit:]]/ }`? Also, which shell and its version do you use?